# Force SSRS display all columns even with empty data

Tags: sql, reporting-services

`How can I have static rows with 12 Months along with dynamic rows and it have to look like one table? I dont have column Budget, I created separate helper table with budget amount for whole year. So I dont know how can I join that table to main query?

```
Select SUM(amount) as Commercial Auto
FROM
JOIN...`
WHERE...
UNION ALL 
Select sum(anotherAmount) as Speciality Casualty
FROM
JOIN
WHERE
```

Should be like that :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM4Zq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is cross join the data you have to a calendar. - this way you can still keep the cells that don't have any numerical data because they will still have the calendar month to show.

Watch your Aggregate - make sure you are doing your cross join right!

```html
WITH Money_CTE AS(
 SELECT
     '1564651.01' AS MonataryData,
     '2' AS MonthNumber
    FROM
     DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT
     '234235.23' AS MonataryData,
        '3' AS MonthNumber
    FROM
     DUAL
    ),
Calendar_CTE AS(
 SELECT
     '1' AS MonthNumber,
        'January' AS MonthName
    FROM
     DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT
     '2' AS MonthNumber,
        'February' AS MonthName
    FROM
     DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT
     '3' AS MonthNumber,
        'March' AS MonthName
    FROM
     DUAL
)
SELECT 
 C.MonthNumber,
    C.MonthName,
 MAX(CASE WHEN M.MonthNumber = C.MonthNumber THEN M.MonataryData ELSE NULL END) AS Money
FROM 
 Money_CTE M
    CROSS JOIN Calendar_CTE C
GROUP BY
 C.MonthNumber,
    C.MonthName
```

Sorry for all the "Dual" crap - I've been forced to deal with Oracle lately.

Comment: Sam. Thank you for your respond. But I need to return all records in Select statement so I can use it in SSRS report. And I got mess. My query consist of 3 giant blocks of statement connected by Union all.  so I just have to encapsulate all 3 of them in one CTE, then cross join in to Calendar_CTE?  Is that right?

Comment: Yes. You have that right. Remember that a Cross Join will return a Cartesian product - quite the mess, but you will need the records that provide the calendar half of the product. You will likely want to make sure that your encapsulating cte only has one record for each of the month data points. In short, the cross join can really mess up your data if you aren't careful - so check to make sure it doesn't